# loading Gif not working Jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

When i submit or click the form button i want to hide the button and show the loading gif and display the message from the php script.

This is my code..

```
$("button#sub").click(function() {

$("div#error").css("color", "red");

if ($("#username").val() == '' || $("#password").val() == '') {

    $("div#error").html("Please enter your account");

}else
    $.post( $("#loginForm").attr("action"), 
            $("#loginForm :input").serializeArray(), 
            function(data) { 
             $("button#sub").delay(100).show(0);
             $("div#load").delay(100).hide(0);
             $("div#error").html(data); 
            });

$("#loginForm").submit(function() {
    return false;
});
```

});

Comment: You'd be better including the relevant HTML, too. Without it we can't see whether you've got your jQuery selectors correct, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code:
add a div with an id content `<div id="content"></div>`

```
// add this code    
$('#content').html('<img id="loader-img" alt="" src="img/loading.gif" width="100" height="100" align="center" />');

// if u dont have an image try this
$('#content').html('Loading... Loading... Loading...');

    $.post( $("#loginForm").attr("action"), 
            $("#loginForm :input").serializeArray(), 
        function(data) { 
         $("button#sub").delay(100).show(0);
         $("div#load").delay(100).hide(0);
         $("div#error").html(data); 

         // and this
         $('#content').html('<div id="load">Loading Complete</div>');
 });
```

Second Option:
You may want to try this.
create index.php, and a folder http inside it create a file data.php and echo something. Create also a folder called img inside it loading.gif. 
Download it from here http://www.ajaxload.info/

Use firefox firebug to debug the return in console. here http://getfirebug.com/

this is index.php

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Ajax Loading</title>

    <style type="text/css">
    div#load{
        padding: 0 3em;
        outline: none;
        border: none;
        color: black;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 700;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        font-size: 1em;
        line-height: 4;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 20px auto;
        display: block;
    }

    #loader-img{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    }

    #content{
        width: 40%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 3em;
        text-align: center;
        color: black;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 600;
    }

    .border{border: 3px solid #fff;     border-radius: 5px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>


    <div id="content">
        <div id="load">Get Data</div>
    </div>
    <pre></pre>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click','#load',function (e){
            e.preventDefault();
            // Adding loading GIF
            $('#content').html('<img id="loader-img" alt="" src="img/loading.gif" width="100" height="100" align="center" />');

            $.post("http/data.php",
            {
                test: "test"
            },
            function(data){
                $('pre').html('Hi I am ' + data + '!').show();
                $('#content').html('<div id="load">Get Data</div>');
            });


        });
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

this is data.php

```
<?php 
     echo 'Test Success';
?>
```

About this line:

```
$(document).on('click','#load',function (e){
                e.preventDefault();
```

is identical to your code:

```
$("button#sub").click(function() {
```

Comment: your 1st option code is not working, i add your first line of code which is the displaying of gif but nothing happens i put it before the post method

Comment: did the image shows? if not add this to your html body ` <div id="content"></div> `

Comment: check the erros using firebug